# Bootstrap font is not responsive as expected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, responsiveness

I'm starting with Bootstrap and everything seems correct when I check the responsiveness with my desktop browser, but when I go on my phone (Iphone 6) it doesn't give me what I'm expecting...

Here are some screenshots :
Desktop (reduced to preview a mobile browser size)
[image]

Phone (Iphone 6)
[image]

We can clearly see that there are some trouble... I might have missed something.

You can inspect my code at this url : http://robeen.fr/v3

Some help would be much appreciated : )

Comment: On a side-note, add `class="img-responsive"` to WordPress logo. It breaks out of the view-port, otherwise.

Comment: Thank for the tip, I'll do it soon : )

Comment: Did you try plugins like http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/ to have responsive fonts ?

Comment: The problem is that when I compare my website to others people that used bootstrap, it's working on their website... I wanna understand what I did wrong... I guess it's in my coding but I can't find out exactly what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

The problem is that i was missing this in my `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pixels for your font sizing. Try `rem`, `em` or `%` based values. You also don't have a `line-height` which is the culprit in your typefaces being cut off. Remember to use responsive formulas to calculate widths. See http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design for more.

Also, your site looks beautiful and you should be proud of the work you've done. :)

Comment: Great ! I'll try that in a minute, thanks a lot for the feedback : )